# how to improve LInQ performance repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, performance, linq

I have using the generic repository pattern in WebAPI with database as postgreSQL. The transaction table has 300 000 to 1 000 000 data. For Reporting purpose, I have to take the count of transaction data join other two table. The LinQ query loads around 1.5 mins. to provide the data. How to optimize or improve the performance?

```
var data = (from emp in (await new Repository<emp>().GetAll()).ToList()
    join trans1 in (await new Repository<trans1>().GetAll()).ToList()
    on emp.staffid equals trans1?.leadstaffid
    join trans2 in (await new Repository<trans2>().GetAll())
    on trans1.statusid equals trans2.statusid
    into tassta
    from ts in tassta.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new { emp, trans1, ts }
    by new { emp.staffid, emp.fullname } into grp
    select new ReportTs
    {
        particulars = grp.FirstOrDefault().emp.fullname.Trim(),
        id = grp.FirstOrDefault().trans1.id,
        staffid = grp.FirstOrDefault().trans1.staffid,
        PByDep = grp.Where(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == 2).Select(ys1 => ys1.trans1.statusid).Count(),
        PFT = grp.Where(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == 3).Select(ys1 => ys1.trans1.statusid).Count(),
        PByC = grp.Where(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == 4).Select(ys1 => ys1.trans1.statusid).Count(),
        PFR = grp.Where(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == 5).Select(ys1 => ys1.trans1.statusid).Count(),
        inid = grp.FirstOrDefault().trans1.inid,
        rowtotal = grp.Count(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == null) +
                  grp.Count(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == 2) +
                  grp.Count(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == 3) +
                  grp.Count(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == 4) +
                  grp.Count(ys => ys.trans1.statusid == 5) ,
        PApp = true,
        CDate = false
    }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: How much data is in there?

Comment: @Stefan, For "trans1" table, it has upto 3Lakhs as of now. It will raise upto 10 Lakhs data in a month itself. For "emp" (employee) table currently, it has 35000 data and trans2 is the parent table of trans1. It has been referred by id column.

Comment: First of all ToList() is suspicious and you have to rely on Querable instead of Enumrable.

Comment: You might want to make a stored procedure out of this... Are you using Entity Framework? Also a Lakh is not an international unit, please use thousands or millions on SO (if it's important to use a specific value).

Comment: @JHBonarius, Could you please share the sample code snippet for the above linQ query to stored procedure in postgreSQL and invoke process in repository pattern. This will help me sort-out the issue.

Comment: @Sathishkumar that will take me a considerable amount of time, that I don't have. TBH, I think this is something that you should be able to do yourself. If you don't understand what Linq or in this case Linq-to-SQL or Entity Framework is doing, i.e. understand the SQL it's generating, then you are not ready to write these kinds of queries. Else you'll end up with the problem you are now facing: 1.5 minute queries or worse. You cannot expect others to do your work for you.

Comment: @JHBonarius, Thanks for your reply. I not asking you to do my work. I just asking for a sample code snippet for it (or) it could be a referral link to sort-out my issue. If you have it, please share it that might help. I have already include the INDEX and tried the table partition and none of them worked for my case. That's the reason I have post my issue.

Comment: Maybe I can look into it later (no guarantees), now I have to take care of my kid.

Comment: Just a hint, most people outside India will have no idea what "lakhs" are.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are running the query in memory after you have fetched all of the data from the database.

I'm supposing that you have a table called 'emp' in your db. When you do

```
 (await new Repository<emp>().GetAll()).ToList()
```

you are moving all of the data from that table to your application memory. This is the same as

```
SELECT * FROM emp
```

Of course this takes quite a lot if you have a lot of tuples in there.

After you have fetched all the data you are using Linq to run an in memory query against those data.

To improve the performance you have to remove that 'ToList()' from the first and second lines, which materializes the data.

After you have done that you have to rewrite the query because the one you have written is not translatable to a SQL query.

Your goal should be to have a query that can be run against your DB so that you fetch only the data you need.

---EDIT---

Here you have two examples.
In the first one all of the data will be fetched from the db and then the query will be run in memory (as you are doing now). In the second one the query will be run in the database and you'll fetch only the desired data.

```
 public class Repository<T>()
 {
      public Task<IQueryable<T>> GetAll(){...}
 }

 public class Examples 
 {

      public async static Task Example1()
      {
           var repository = new Repository<emp>();

           var emps =  await repository.GetAll().ToList();

           var reports = from emp in emps
           where emp.Id > 10
           select new ReportData(){
                ...
           }


      }

      public async static Task Example2()
      {
           var repository = new Repository<emp>();

           var emps =  await repository.GetAll();

           var reports = (from emp in emps
           where emp.Id > 10
           select new ReportData(){
                ...
           }).ToList();


      }
 }
```

Keep in mind that although the syntax is very similar those two examples do very different things.

In the first case the Linq query will be compiled in foreach loops, in the second case it will end up in a query for postgres. This means that in this case you cannot call methods that cannot be translated to a postgres query (i.e particulars = grp.FirstOrDefault().emp.fullname.Trim())

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was not clear on the above statement. Could you please provide the sample code snippet based on the above linQ query (which I have posted). This will help me to understand better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've added two examples in my answer

Comment: The second one will not necessarily work unless you do an `ToEnumerable()` before the projection. (limitation of linq-to-sql). (Not fully sure on this, but it's my experience). And note that [PostgreSQL actually has a trim function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-trim-function/), so that last query might actually work. EF core is quite smart these days.

Comment: @JHBonarius doing ToEnumerable() materializes the IQueryable just like ToList() does so this falls back to the first scenario

Comment: Yes I know. What I'm saying is that linq-to-sql cannot convert everything, so **sometimes** you have to convert in order for the query to work. E.g. `_ctx.Entities.Where(x => x.Id > 10).ToEnumerable().Select(x => MyFunction(x)).ToList()`

Comment: Yes that's perfectly right. In order to improve the performance it'd be better to move as much as possible before the materialization (before the call to ToEnumerable, ToList, ToArray or whatever executes the query)